# JavaFX Spinner - Background Color

Tags: css, javafx, colors, spinner

I have looked all over the forums and haven't found anything, maybe not using the right key words. Can someone assist me in styling this outer, border-like, part of javafx spinner via css. Thanks!

[javafx spinner with white border/bg color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgyAH.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you create a dark theme in your JavaFX application, you can use -fx-base in .root styling (in style.css) then you have all your JavaFX controls in dark:

   .root {
   -fx-base: rgba(60, 63, 65, 255);
   }
2. If you want to change the styling only for Spinner control, you can use -fx-base for .spinner in css:

   .spinner {
   -fx-base: rgba(60, 63, 65, 255);
   }

Other css properties of the Spinner control you can find in modena.css.